# Why I can't submit the form, value always required even if not

Tags: php, validation, symfony-1.4, symfony-forms

I've this code in my `_form.php` template (some fields irrelevant are omited):

```
<?php echo $form['correo_madre'] ?>
<?php echo $form['correo_madre']->renderError() ?>
```

In my AlumnosForm.class.php have this one:

```
public function configure() {
   $this->validatorSchema['correo_padre'] = new sfValidatorEmail(array(), array('invalid' => 'La dirección de correo no es válida'));
   $this->validatorSchema['correo_madre'] = new sfValidatorEmail(array(), array('invalid' => 'La dirección de correo no es válida'));

   $this->validatorSchema->setPostValidator(new sfValidatorCallback(array('callback' => array($this, 'checkFields'))));
}

public function checkFields($validator, $values) {
  if ((!empty($values['alumnos_nombre_padre']) &&    
       !empty($values['alumnos_apellidos_padre']) &&
       !empty($values['alumnos_rut_padre']) &&
       !empty($values['alumnos_telefono_padre']) &&
       !empty($values['alumnos_direccion_padre']) &&
       !empty($values['alumnos_correo_padre'])) ||
       (!empty($values['alumnos_nombre_madre']) &&
       !empty($values['alumnos_apellidos_madre']) &&
       !empty($values['alumnos_rut_madre']) &&
       !empty($values['alumnos_telefono_madre']) &&
       !empty($values['alumnos_direccion_madre']) &&
       !empty($values['alumnos_correo_madre']))) {
            return $values;
        } else {
            throw new sfValidatorError($validator, 'Los datos de uno de los dos padres son requeridos!!!');
   }
}
```

I check also BaseAlumnosForm.class.php and field isn't required in validators:

```
'correo_madre' => new sfValidatorString(array('max_length' => 100, 'required' => false))
```

When I try to submit the form proccess fails with

> Required

message, why?

Comment: Did you set a validator for every field?! If not, you should do it. And in _form.php template have you render hidden fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you re-define your validator inside the `configure()` of `AlumnosForm`, the definition inside `BaseAlumnosForm` is overrided.

So you should focus on the validator inside `AlumnosForm` *(did you define it twice inside this class or is it only a typo?)*

By default, [a validator is required](http://trac.symfony-project.org/browser/branches/1.4/lib/validator/sfValidatorBase.class.php#L32):

> required:    `true` if the value is required, `false` otherwise **(default to `true`)**

That's why the one inside the Base is explicitly at `false`. In your case, the overrided definition, remove this `false` because you didn't define it.

Force it and it should fix your problem:

```
$this->validatorSchema['correo_padre'] = new sfValidatorEmail(
    array('required' => false),
    array('invalid'  => 'La dirección de correo no es válida')
);
```

Comment: you're right I miss the `required` part. Now I've fixed but I still getting the same error even when all required fields have values. I suspect the problem is the postValidator, correct me if I wrong but I want to said `if all fields _padre has values or all fields _madre has values` then return true else throw sfValidatorError, is my sentece wrong?

Comment: Does the error message still says `Required`? If so, the problem isn't related to your callback validator since you throw a message that is not required. And you can check by removing the `setPostValidator`.

Comment: I got the error, the fields name in my postValidator function was wrong, I fixed and now it works